# How to benchmark small file (5kb) in ceph

Tags: ceph

I have read this article: https://tracker.ceph.com/projects/ceph/wiki/Benchmark_Ceph_Cluster_Performance

But the problems is they benchmark a 4MB file while i need like to benchmark 1000 5kb file

Is there anyway to do it, like the `dd if=/dev/null of={location} bs = {size} count = {numberoffile} oflag=dsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `man rados`:

> **-b block_size**
>     Set the block size for put/get/append ops and for write benchmarking.

and:

> **bench seconds mode [ -b objsize ] [ -t threads ]**
>   [...]
>   Note:  -b  objsize option is valid only in write mode.
>   [...]

This is also mentioned on the page you linked:

> You can also add the -t parameter to increase the concurrency of reads and writes (defaults to 16 threads), or the -b parameter to change the size of the object being written (defaults to 4 MB).

To benchmark 1000 5KB object writes:

```
rados bench -p scbench 20 write -b 5120 -t 50
```